# Variable for the dimensions of a multivariable array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to generalize some code in a function so that I can read different JSON formatted input and determine system information from each.  For brevity, I am not including all of the code.  In the actual code, I am retrieving the value of $length from a database.

Here is an example:

```
function readHostname($json, $length) {
    $content = json_decode($json, true);
    $hostname = $content[$length];
}


$json = file_get_contents($url1, false, $context);
$length = "[0]['cluster']['nodes'][0][hostName]";
echo readHostname($json, $length);

$json = file_get_contents($url2, false, $context);
$length = "[0]['components']['serviceName']";
echo readHostname($json, $length);
```

For reference url1 would return JSON such as:

```
    [
     {
      "cluster": {
         "nodes": [
             { "name": "cluster1",
               "hostName": "alpha" 
             },
             { "name": "cluster2",
               "hostName": "beta"
             }
          ]
      }
     },
     {
       "cluster": {
         "nodes": [
              { "name": "prod_cluster1",
                "hostName": "oscar"
              },
              {
                "name": "prod_cluster2",
                "hostName": "delta"
              }
           ]
       }
     }
    ]
```

and url2 would return json:

```
    [
     {
      "compenents": {
          "serviceName" : "hostname1",
          "environment" : "produciton"
      }
     }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want flexible access to nested array structures. Replace your `readHostname` function with this:

```
function readHostname($json, $length) {
    $content = json_decode($json, true);
    preg_replace_callback('/\[([^]]+)\]+/', function($m) use(&$content) {
       $index = $m[1];
       $content = $content[preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $index) ? intval($index) : trim($index, "'\"")];
    }, $length);
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: the problem here is defining the $nesting within the code.  Let's assume that comes from a different source, like a database.   like $nesting = read from database

Comment: Well, this "read from database" aspect was added to the question after I posted my answer :-)

Comment: I adapted the answer to the reformulated question

Comment: Thanks for adjusting!  Let me check it out and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract the process and use recursion.

```
function getHost($payload,$hostName){

    $array = is_array($payload) ? $payload : json_decode($payload,true);
    if(json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE){
        return;
    }

    foreach(array_keys($array) as $key){
        if($array[$key] == $hostName){
            unset($array[$key]);
            return $array[key($array)];
        }
    }

    return getHost($array[key($array)],$hostName);
}

echo getHost($payload,"cluster1");
echo getHost($payload,"hostname1");
```

Comment: This is assuming I'm only looking for hostName from the json?  I tried to change it up a bit.. one json I may be looking for hostName, one may be serviceName, one may be something else entirely.  The point is I want to determine that with the $length variable.  So assume I do a select from a db, and do a foreach on them.  foreach ($result_from_db as $search) { echo getHost($payload, $search) }   
Is that right?

Comment: I think this may work too, but haven't tested it out yet.

Comment: It look like to me that you were trying to get to parse out a piece of that object.  The function will return the other key of the array, given the second parameter.  I wasn't sure that was exactly what you were trying to do, but the concept I laid should enable you parse out any object, no matter what key or number of dimensions.